# VSCode remote ssh terminal not using environment variables

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, environment-variables

I'm using an Ubuntu machine as a headless dev machine. I am connecting through VSCode Remote-SSH. I open a terminal from within vscode and try to run 'go' but I get told the command cannot be found. I try it within a normal terminal without any issue. I noticed the environment variable list is vastly different between the vscode terminal and the traditional terminal. I placed the go executable in /etc/environment.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?